# Why is variable not being populated with data from Get-AzADServicePrinciple?

Tags: powershell, entra-id

Can someone tell me why the variable isn't populated with anything, but if I run Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString $appName then it returns as expected?

```
Connect-AzAccount
$appName = "AzureADGuestLifecycleMgmt"
$svcPrinciple = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString $appName
Write-Host $svcPrinciple
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because the `Get-AzADServicePrincipal` is returning an object, and you need to identify which part of the object you want to write out to the console.

I would suggest selecting the specific values you are trying to write out, or just call the variable you are assigning the output to.

example:

```perl
Connect-AzAccount
$appName = "AzureADGuestLifecycleMgmt"
$svcPrinciple = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString $appName
$svcPrinciple
```